# Why does my `recursive_print_proof` not work?

Tags: python, loops, logic, infinite-loop, propositional-calculus

For an assignment we had to write Python code that performs resolution on a propositional logic KB.

All code seems to work fine, except for the `recursive_print_proof`. When running the program, it will keep running until you tell it to stop.

What it should do is output a proof, based on the resolution. However, it seems to get stuck in a loop.

Hopefully anyone can help me.

`recursive_print_proof` can be found almost at the end. My code is:

```py
def recursive_print_proof(idx, clause_set):
    kb = init()
    if contains_empty_clause(kb):
        inferred = []
        for i in range(len(kb)):
            for j in range(i,len(kb)):
                if can_resolve(kb[i],kb[j]):
                    resolvent = resolve_clauses(kb[i],kb[j])
                    inferred.append(resolvent)
                    if clause_set[idx].equals(resolvent):
                        idx2 = find_index_of_clause(kb[j],clause_set)
                        recursive_print_proof(idx2,clause_set)
                        idx2 = find_index_of_clause(kb[i],clause_set)
                        recursive_print_proof(idx2,clause_set)
                        # printing
                        clause_set[idx].print_clause()
                        print(" is inferred from", end=" ")
                        kb[i].print_clause()
                        print(" and", end=" ")
                        kb[j].print_clause()
                        print(".")
                        break
                    break
                break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know why the code is spinning in `recursive_print_proof`...

your `recursive_print_proof` method loops on a condition `while not contains_empty_clause(kb):` which will never be false. So it keeps spinning.

Perhaps you want it to be `if not contains_empty_clause(kb):` ?

Comment: Yeah, you are right. The program is indeed looping on `while not contains_empty_clause(kb):`. I tried changing it to an `if`-statement, now the program does not loop anymore, but I still get no outcome. Any ideas on why this might be?